# Why did Catherine Tramell use the pseudonym "Catherine Woolf"?

Tags: character, basic-instinct

In [*Basic Instinct*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103772/), Catherine Tramell writes under the pseudonym "Catherine Woolf".

[image: Catherine Woolf]

**Is there ever an explanation given as to why she chose that particular pseudonym?  Does the name have any significance to her character in the film?**

Comment: Virginia Woolf was a famous author. She is known for (among other things) saying that a woman needed money and a room of her own if she wanted to write.  I wonder if this is a reference to that.